# Error when Installing java 8 on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java

I used this commands to install java 8 on my ubuntu servers:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

But at one server I have a issue when I type apt-get install oracle-java8-installer....and after accepting terms...

Here is the issue:

```
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-06-02 21:25:56--  download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 2.16.4.176, 2.16.4.178
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.16.4.176|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-06-02 21:25:56--  edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2.21.253.143, 2a02:26f0:2d:481::2d3e, 2a02:26f0:2d:483::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2.21.253.143|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: (download(.)oracle(.)com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1496431676_6bda1c9f8e9f814775eb5960113152cc [following]
--2017-06-02 21:25:56--  download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1496431676_6bda1c9f8e9f814775eb5960113152cc
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download(.)oracle(.)com)|2.16.4.176|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-06-02 21:25:58 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: repository problems are inevitable when you're using an unsupported distro. Please install 14.04, 16.04 or 17.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands are illustrated in details here
[Install Oracle Java 8 / 9 in Ubuntu 16.04, Linux Mint 18](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/)

Simply, steps are:

1. Add the PPA. Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the command:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   ```
2. Update and install the installer script

   ```
   sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
   ```
3. Check the Java version: To check the Java version after installing the package, run command:

   ```
   javac -version
   ```
4. Set Java environment variables

   ```
   sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
   ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/718079)

Comment: Didn't think about that, but yes, this really makes sense. Thanks for the advice.